# Problem with reading file in C#

Tags: c#, encoding

I have file in cp866 encoding. In some places it's file contains symbol 0 in hex code. When I try to read this file with File.ReadAllText() or streamReader.Read() it's stop reading file in this symbol. How to solve this problem?
**[UPDATE]**
I think that symbol 0x0 means end of file.

Comment: What is "866-th encoding"? What is a symbox?

Comment: Hi, can you show the way you are using streamReader.Read() ? I think we should use an overload with specific encoding...

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept that answer to remove this question from the unanswered list.

Comment: Hey, could you add the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. I think you should read file as binary file not as text file.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
string text = File.ReadAllText("foo.txt", encoding);
```

That assuming you want *code page* 866.

I don't know enough about CP866 to know whether it would normally contain 0 bytes... but if your text file is *valid* CP866, the above should read it.